# Pandas: Convert time into seconds for all values in column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataframe that represents time as minutes and seconds with the format mm:ss.ms or 00:00.00.  I need to convert the entire column of values into seconds with dtype float.  The dataframe column is shown below:

```
resultsorig['fastestLapTime']
Out[41]: 
0        01:27.5
1        01:27.7
2        01:28.1
3        01:28.6
4        01:27.4
  
24735    01:21.8
24736    01:22.5
24737    01:22.0
24738    01:20.4
24739    01:24.0
Name: fastestLapTime, Length: 24740, dtype: object
```

Everything I have found hasn't worked.

UPDATE: I've tried the following in the past and it has worked, but it's not working for this dataframe and I'm not sure why:

```
resultsorig=resultsorig[~resultsorig['fastestLapTime'].str.contains(":")]
resultsorig['fastestLapTime']=pd.to_numeric([resultsorig['fastestLapTime'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
df['fastestLapTime']=df['fastestLapTime'].apply(lambda x: float(x.split(':')[0])*60+float(x.split(':')[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide an expected output so I took a guess

`df['fastestLapTime'].map(lambda x: sum(x * float(t) for x, t in zip([60.0, 1.0], x.split(':')))`

```
0    87.5
1    87.7
2    88.1
3    88.6
4    87.4
5    81.8
6    82.5
7    82.0
8    80.4
9    84.0
```

Comment: Sorry expected outcome would be the same value but just in seconds.  So for example row one would look like 87.5 as opposed to 1:27.5

Comment: updated and sorry I miss understood the time format

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas `to_timedelta()` function to convert these strings into timedelta values. The timedelta values have a `total_seconds()` method that will give you the results you want. In pandas, you can access the `total_seconds()` method via the `dt` accessor.

```
import pandas as pd
resultsorig = pd.DataFrame(['01:27.5', '01:27.7', '01:28.1', '01:28.6', '01:27.4'], columns = ['fastestLapTime'])

pd.to_timedelta("00:" + resultsorig['fastestLapTime']).dt.total_seconds()
```

results in

```
0    87.5
1    87.7
2    88.1
3    88.6
4    87.4
Name: fastestLapTime, dtype: float64
```

The `"00:" + resultsorig['fastestLapTime']` is necessary because `to_timedelta()` expects times in "HH:MM:SS.m" format, so this adds the hours part to the beginning of the strings.